# LDAP Configure error. ldapsearch return no such object, ldapadd returns Invalid credentials

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm new to ldap, try to configure ldap, but found below errors. Could someone help me on this? Thanks

[image]

Below is my slapd.conf file
[image]

Below is some content from lili.ldif.
[image]

Could someone help me figure out the reason? Thanks

Comment: ldap     30960     1  0 Jul31 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/slapd -u ldap -h ldapi:/// ldap:///

Comment: Looks like the rootDN is `cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com` but you are using `-D "cn=root,dc=test,dc=com"`. Maybe that's why you are getting the invalid credentials error?